# How to prevent text from tucking underneath left floated image

Tags: html, css

I would like for the text to be displayed to the right of the image with some spacing in between them. The problem I'm having is that the responsiveness isn't the best. Is there a better way to prevent the text from tucking underneath the images when resizing?

```css
#expertise-section {
  background-color: #bce4b8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px 0 0;
  min-height: 650px;
  width: 100%;
} /* Adjusts section sizing, padding and text alignment */



/*------------------------------------------------
    START OF EXPERTISE SECTION STYLING
------------------------------------------------*/

#expertise-section h1 {
  color: #000;
  font-family: "Lobster Two", cursive;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: -2%;
} /* Sets colour, font, font size and position of the h1 title within the expertise section */

.expertise-section-title {
  margin-top: 0;
} /* Sets margin of the expertise title */

.expertise-section-title:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
} /* Creates horizontal line for the expertise section titles and sets positioning */

.expertise-section-title span {
  background: #bce4b8;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
} /* Sets background of the expertise section background and sets padding for spacing between title and hr line */

.expertise-section-content {
  margin-left: 14%;
  margin-right: 14%;
  margin-top: 4%;
}

.expertise-section-content img {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: -2.25%;
  max-width: 45vh;
  max-height: 30vh;
  border-radius: 12.5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
} /* Sets size and positioning of image within the expertise section */

.expertise-section-content p {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2.2vh;
}

.expertise-section-content button {
  font-size: 2vh;
  padding: 0.6em 2em;
  border-radius: 35px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #339a9a;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  /* clear: both; May not need this included */
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.expertise-section-content button a {
  color: white;
}

.expertise-section-content button:hover {
  background-color: #004e4f;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

/*------------------------------------------------
    END OF EXPERTISE SECTION STYLING
  ------------------------------------------------*/




@media only screen and (max-width: 1606px) {
  #expertise-section h1 {
    margin-top: -4%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
  } /* Sets colour, font, font size and position of the h1 title within the expertise section */

  .expertise-section-content {
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    margin-top: 3%;
  }

  .expertise-section-content img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 30%;
    margin-right: 30%;
    width: 40%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
  } /* Sets size and positioning of image within the expertise section */

  .expertise-section-content p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
  }

  .expertise-section-content button {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 6.5%;
  }
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 815px) {
  
  /*------------------------------
    START OF EXPERTISE SECTION
  --------------------------------*/

  #expertise-section h1 {
    margin-top: -10%;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #000;
  } /* Makes changes to sizing and positioning of the h1 tag */

  .expertise-section-title {
    margin-top: 0;
  } /* Sets margin of the expertise title */

  .expertise-section-title:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-top: solid 1px #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
  } /* Creates horizontal line for the expertise section titles and sets positioning */

  .expertise-section-title span {
    background: #bce4b8;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  } /* Sets background of the expertise section background and sets padding for spacing between title and hr line */

  .expertise-section-content {
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    margin-top: 6%;
  }

  .expertise-section-content img {
    margin-left: 12.5%;
    margin-right: 12.5%;
    width: 75%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 8%;
  } /* Sets size and positioning of image within the expertise section */

  .expertise-section-content p {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .expertise-section-content button {
    font-size: 26px;
    /* clear: both; May not need this included */
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 15%;
    padding: 0.4em 1.5em;
  }

  /*------------------------------
    END OF EXPERTISE SECTION
  --------------------------------*/
}
```

```html
<section id="expertise-section">
      <h1 class="expertise-section-title"><span>Why Choose Me?</span></h1>

    <div class="expertise-section-content">
      <div class="element">
        <img src="http://nathan-bayne.co.uk/images/pexels-anna-tarazevich-5910768.jpg" alt="image"/>
        <p>My approach is warm and understanding. I am here to listen to you and help you to make sense of difficult times.
        If you would like to find out more, you can read about my experience and qualifications by clicking the button below.
        </p>
        <button onclick="location.href='findoutmore.html'" type="button">Find Out More</button> <!-- Links to another page-->
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Any better solution would be appreciated.

Comment: The way I have my min height set for the section isn't the best responsively either. depending on the size of the screen, the spacing is a bit off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? Remove some of the margin at certain viewports and at the smallest viewport, removed the float on the image so that they stack.

```css
#expertise-section {
  background-color: #bce4b8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px 0 0;
  min-height: 650px;
  width: 100%;
} /* Adjusts section sizing, padding and text alignment */



/*------------------------------------------------
    START OF EXPERTISE SECTION STYLING
------------------------------------------------*/

#expertise-section h1 {
  color: #000;
  font-family: "Lobster Two", cursive;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: -2%;
} /* Sets colour, font, font size and position of the h1 title within the expertise section */

.expertise-section-title {
  margin-top: 0;
} /* Sets margin of the expertise title */

.expertise-section-title:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
} /* Creates horizontal line for the expertise section titles and sets positioning */

.expertise-section-title span {
  background: #bce4b8;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
} /* Sets background of the expertise section background and sets padding for spacing between title and hr line */

.expertise-section-content {
  margin-left: 14%;
  margin-right: 14%;
  margin-top: 4%;
}

.expertise-section-content img {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: -2.25%;
  max-width: 45vh;
  max-height: 30vh;
  border-radius: 12.5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
} /* Sets size and positioning of image within the expertise section */

.expertise-section-content p {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2.2vh;
}

.expertise-section-content button {
  font-size: 2vh;
  padding: 0.6em 2em;
  border-radius: 35px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #339a9a;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  /* clear: both; May not need this included */
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.expertise-section-content button a {
  color: white;
}

.expertise-section-content button:hover {
  background-color: #004e4f;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

/*------------------------------------------------
    END OF EXPERTISE SECTION STYLING
  ------------------------------------------------*/




@media only screen and (max-width: 1606px) {
  #expertise-section h1 {
    margin-top: -4%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
  } /* Sets colour, font, font size and position of the h1 title within the expertise section */

  .expertise-section-content {
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    margin-top: 3%;
  }

  .expertise-section-content img {
    width: 40%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
  } /* Sets size and positioning of image within the expertise section */

  .expertise-section-content p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
  }

  .expertise-section-content button {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 6.5%;
  }
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 815px) {
  
  /*------------------------------
    START OF EXPERTISE SECTION
  --------------------------------*/

  #expertise-section h1 {
    margin-top: -10%;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #000;
  } /* Makes changes to sizing and positioning of the h1 tag */

  .expertise-section-title {
    margin-top: 0;
  } /* Sets margin of the expertise title */

  .expertise-section-title:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-top: solid 1px #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
  } /* Creates horizontal line for the expertise section titles and sets positioning */

  .expertise-section-title span {
    background: #bce4b8;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  } /* Sets background of the expertise section background and sets padding for spacing between title and hr line */

  .expertise-section-content {
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    margin-top: 6%;
  }

  .expertise-section-content img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 95%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 8%;
    float: none; /* stacks on smaller viewports */
  } /* Sets size and positioning of image within the expertise section */

  .expertise-section-content p {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .expertise-section-content button {
    font-size: 26px;
    /* clear: both; May not need this included */
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 15%;
    padding: 0.4em 1.5em;
  }

  /*------------------------------
    END OF EXPERTISE SECTION
  --------------------------------*/
}
```

```html
<section id="expertise-section">
      <h1 class="expertise-section-title"><span>Why Choose Me?</span></h1>

    <div class="expertise-section-content">
      <div class="element">
        
        <p><img src="http://nathan-bayne.co.uk/images/pexels-anna-tarazevich-5910768.jpg" alt="image"/>My approach is warm and understanding. I am here to listen to you and help you to make sense of difficult times.
        If you would like to find out more, you can read about my experience and qualifications by clicking the button below.
        </p>
        <button onclick="location.href='findoutmore.html'" type="button">Find Out More</button> <!-- Links to another page-->
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: That definitely has made a difference, however, it still tucks under the image ever so slightly. I'll try messing around with it to fix it.

Comment: Is there something that can be sorted with the height of the section to adjust when the text/image changes size?

Comment: @NathanBayne Usually in instance like this, I will manually create a media query when it "breaks" in the browser and adjust font size or whatever I need to do at that specific viewport width when I see it failing. Sometimes I will have several media queries bouncing widths or font-sizes so it never looks broken.

Comment: I do have media queries but I'll just add another one for the likes of this example. Thanks a lot.